# Как получить значения по ключу в ассоциативном массиве?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM book_items WHERE `genre_value`= '$genreBook' AND `year_publishing_book` BETWEEN '$publishing_first_interval' AND '$publishing_second_interval' AND `number_of_page` BETWEEN '$page_first_int' AND '$page_second_int' AND `price` BETWEEN '$price_first_int' AND '$price_second_int' AND `author_value`= '$author'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$datas = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $datas[] = $row;
    }
}
```

В обычный массив добавляю строку из моего запроса в виде ассоциативного массива. Вопрос: как в foreach получить необходимые значения каждого ассоц.массива по определённым заданным ключам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот таким циклом например можно вывести все genre_value или любое другое поле таблицы

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($datas); $i++){
   echo ( $datas[$i]["genre_value"]);
}
```

Или через foreach

```
foreach ($datas as $row){
  echo ( $row["genre_value"]);
}
```